# legecy UI in hadoop 2.7.0

Tags: hadoop

How can we enable Legacy UI in Hadoop 2.7.0?

http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have access to *your* `localhost`... You might want to edit your question and provide a link to a screenshot or some documentation page showing the desired interface.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you playing with a pseudo cluster (single node), namenode hosts the web service, you should be able to open the that UI as long as namenode is started even with a minimal number of properties set in `hdfs-site.xml` and `core-site.xml`.

So it mostly looks like your namenode is not running properly, 1st thing is to check the namenode log, hdfs-hdfs-namenode-...log. See what happened ...